# Copy vagrant box locally

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

I have a vagrant box running on VirtualBox, and I need to make a copy (with all its existing config and data), so that I can make changes on it without affecting the original.

The problem is that my original box came as a file package - the internet connection where I'm working with is extremely slow so someone else copied their vagrant and virtualbox folders to my machine. Thus there is no

```
config.vm.box_url
```

to use.

How can I accomplish this?

Edit: I am using Vagrant 1.2.2

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Create a new box from your existing vm:

- cd into the directory with your Vagrant file
- run `vagrant package` This will export a box file called package.box by default
- run `vagrant box add foo package.box` to add package.box to your existing boxes.  (Assuming you are using VirtualBox and not VMWare)
- run `vagrant box list` to verify it was added.

Now you can just create a new folder, run `vagrant init` as normal and set your box to the following:

```
 config.vm.box = "foo"
```

The new VM will spin up with the exact data that was present in the previous VM.

[Vagrant Documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html)

---

Additionally checkout a new product from the creators of Vagrant called [Packer](http://www.packer.io). It will do this same thing, but allow you to copy your vm's to other providers (Amazon, VirtualBox ect..)

**Update**

Newer versions of Vagrant have two commands that make the above steps unnecessary.

```
vagrant share
vagrant package
```

`Vagrant share` will upload your box to [atlas](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/session)
`Vagrant package` will create a .box file automatically.

For more information, type in `vagrant --help`

Comment: Seems like a great way, but unfortunately I am using a different version of vagrant, while your commands seem to be for 1.0.x

Comment: @xiankai I am running 1.2.2 and I have verified that these steps work for me. I made a few tweaks to my answer for clarity, give it another try and let me know what errors you get.

Comment: Ah, after looking at the link you posted, I tried `vagrant package` instead of `vagrant box package` and it seems like I'm on the right track now!

Comment: vagrant package is correct. That was a typo on my part.